# Should single developers branch?

Tags: svn

As a newbie to SVN, I'm wondering if there are any advantages to creating "branches" if I'm going to be a single developer on a project.

Thanks!

Comment: Branches let you keep things you're working on separate from each other, and also let you separate work done on individual releases from work done on mainline; that latter is entirely essential to maintenance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/360887/62576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you're a single developer, it doesn't mean that you won't have a need for branches on occasion.

I'm a single developer on one of my apps at work. I have branched **on occasion** because I'm working on a large-scale change to the system that takes several weeks/months to build out (new features plus some refactoring) *while* having to maintain the current codebase.

90% of the time, I don't branch, as it's not necessary for what I'm doing. That remaining 10% of the time, it can be a lifesaver.

I do tag all of my releases, but that's a separate discussion altogether - those tags are used as easy references to the state of the code at a point in time, for build/deploy purposes for our various environments. It also gives me a handy way to back out a change by reverting back to the previous tag.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer!

Answer (score 3):

I would not create branches during normal development but would TAG releases.  Then if I find that I have a release that I have to support with a single bug fix (i.e. a dot release) I could create a branch from that tag and check in my fix to the trunk and the release branch so that I can get quick fixes out without releasing unfinished features.